# CAS Spring client - redirection back to the applicatrion is failing because of ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: java, spring, cas

With the below configuration during the first request, its redirecting to CAS server. But after login, its not redirecting back to the application. This is what is happening:

1. Open https://localhost:8443/test
2. Redirecting to https://localhost:9443/cas/login?service=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8443%2Ftest%2F
3. After entering correct credentials, its not redirecting back to the application. URL on browser is the same CAS login URL and the page is broken because of ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

   ```
   <security:http entry-point-ref="casEntryPoint">
       <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
       <security:custom-filter position="CAS_FILTER"
           ref="casFilter" />
   </security:http>

   <bean id="casEntryPoint"
       class="org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationEntryPoint">
       <property name="loginUrl" value="https://localhost:9443/cas/login/" />
       <property name="serviceProperties" ref="serviceProperties" />
   </bean>

   <bean id="casFilter"
       class="org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationFilter">
       <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
   </bean>

   <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
       <security:authentication-provider
           ref="casAuthenticationProvider" />
   </security:authentication-manager>

   <bean id="casAuthenticationProvider"
       class="org.springframework.security.cas.authentication.CasAuthenticationProvider">
       <property name="authenticationUserDetailsService">
           <bean
               class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper">
               <constructor-arg ref="userService" />
           </bean>
       </property>
       <property name="serviceProperties" ref="serviceProperties" />
       <property name="ticketValidator">
           <bean class="org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ServiceTicketValidator">
               <constructor-arg index="0" value="https://localhost:9443/cas/" />
           </bean>
       </property>
       <property name="key" value="an_id_for_this_auth_provider_only" />
   </bean>

   <security:user-service id="userService">
       <security:user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
   </security:user-service>

   <bean id="serviceProperties" class="org.springframework.security.cas.ServiceProperties">
       <property name="service" value="https://localhost:8443/test/" />
       <property name="sendRenew" value="false" />
   </bean>
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is resolved when I changed pattern of below configuration from /** to /newviews/** which is specific to my UI files.

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/newviews/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
```